# Identify the previous question number

Tags: hyperref, exam

Using exam class, I want to identify the previous question number.

For example when you have 3 questions.

Q1
Q2
Q3

I want to insert a piece of code between Q1 and Q2 and the result of that code will state `the previous question is 1`.

Likewise, between Q2 and Q3 the code will state `the previous question is 2`.

If you tried to put the code after the last question, the code will state `end of question`.

I have my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    
\question[1] This is Q1.\\
\textbf{The previous question was 1.} % This is what to figure out.


\question This is Q2
\begin{parts}
    \part[1] Q2 Part a
\end{parts}
\textbf{The previous question was 2.}
\question[1] This is Q3.\\
\textbf{The previous question was 3.}
\question This is Q4
\begin{parts}
    \part
    \begin{subparts}
        \subpart[1]
    \end{subparts}
\end{parts}
\textbf{The previous question was 4.}
\question[1] This is Q5.\\
\textbf{The previous question was 5.}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I've highlighted my desired results in bold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt,addpoints]{exam}

\newcommand{\lastquestion}{%
    % The class exam writes the definition of \exam@numquestions
    % in the .aux file. In the first LaTeX run, \numquestions sees
    % that \exam@numquestions is missing and expands to \mbox{...??}
    % that breaks \ifnum.
    \ifcsname exam@numquestions\endcsname
        \ifnum\value{question}<\numquestions\relax
            \thequestion
        \else
            end of question%
        \fi
    \else
        \thequestion
    \fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    
\question[1] This is Q1.\\
\textbf{The previous question was \lastquestion.}

\question This is Q2
\begin{parts}
    \part[1] Q2 Part a
\end{parts}
\textbf{The previous question was \lastquestion.}
\question[1] This is Q3.\\
\textbf{The previous question was \lastquestion.}
\question This is Q4
\begin{parts}
    \part
    \begin{subparts}
        \subpart[1]
    \end{subparts}
\end{parts}
\textbf{The previous question was \lastquestion.}
\question[1] This is Q5.\\
\textbf{The previous question was \lastquestion.}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn't decipher the .aux file like you did, but i learnt something new. Thank you!

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks for the edit. Didn't realize that.

Comment: is it possible to modify the macro such that is the question goes over the page, it returns something like 'question 3 continues on page 2'